# How to add new ACF fields by PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Whole day I have been working on this trouble but could not find needed information. Okay, I need adding new fields in the ACF group by PHP. I tested function  acf_add_local_field. Nothing working. I see that function go to $store->set( $key, $field )->alias( $key, $name );. And everything should be okay but fields not add. Please, help me. How I can add new ACF fields by PHP? Only fields without group. I have needed group.

```html
acf_add_local_field(
                                array(
                                    'key'   => "generalInfo_".$value,
                                    'label' => $value, 
                                    'name' => "generalInfo_".$value, 
                                    'type' => 'text', 
                                    'parent' => 'generalInfo', 
                                    'parent_layout' => 'group_6187fed087950',
                                    'instructions' => '', 
                                    'required' => 0, 
                                    'conditional_logic' => 0, 
                                    'wrapper' => array('width' => '70')));
                        }
```

I add this code to a custom page template.

Comment: Can you show how and where did you used acf_add_local_field?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: _"I add this code to a custom page template."_ - not sure that is a correct place to do it; it might simply be too late to have the desired effect, when it happens in a page template. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/ talks about doing this in the functions.php, resp. using the `acf/init` action.

Comment: I have added this code in functions.php too, but it does not work.

Comment: I have one task which should be done with ACF. I need to add a custom field in the group directly by PHP. The script can fire once in a day.

Comment: Follow the documentation that @CBroe linked - That explains how to register it to a field group.

Comment: @Stender I read this documentation yesterday. Examples do not work.